# Get BeanCreationException when try to add Jackson Library

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, apache-camel

I have a simple Hello World example that passes a Map to Camel and displays the values to the console via Log4J.  I want to expand this example to render this map in JSON by adding the Jackson library to my Camel applicationContext.xml

First I tried adding the following XML tags to my applicationContext.xml (as specified at 
http://camel.apache.org/json.html under "Using JSON in Spring DSL")

```
<camel:dataFormats>
    <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
</camel:dataFormats>
```

But when I add this to my applicationContext.xml, and run my Java code I get the following XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException message:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dataFormats'.     One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/
 spring":route}' is expected.
```

Moving these tags inside or outside of my camelContext yields the same error (just a longer list of URLs when inside the camelContext).

Is there something else I need to specify in my ApplicationContext.xml?

Here is my current applicationContext.xml:

UPDATED: The following xml now works.  Had to move the location of the dataFormats XML tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<context:component-scan base-package="sample" />
<context:annotation-config />

<camel:camelContext id="HelloWorldContext">

<camel:dataFormats>
  <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
</camel:dataFormats>

<camel:route>

     <camel:from
          uri="timer://hello.world.request.timer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000" />
     <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.request?level=INFO?showAll=true" />
     <camel:bean ref="helloWorld" />
     <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.response?level=INFO?showAll=true" />
</camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
   <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="transacted" value="false" />
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost" />
  <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
  <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" />
</bean>

<bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
  <property name="queuePrefetch" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="1" />
  <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
  <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
  <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `dateFormats` and `json` elements are part of the `camel` namespace.](http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd) You need to specify that

```
<camel:dataFormats>
    <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
</camel:dataFormats>
```

Comment: I think you should also prefix the 'json' tag.

Comment: @adam Yes, missed it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios and Adam.  I modified my ApplicationContext.xml to add these changes( also updated the xml above), and now I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 25; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'camel:dataFormats'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":route}' is expected.

Comment: @erj2code Please update (edit) your question with these new details/changes.

Comment: @Sotirios Just did :-)

Comment: @erj2code If you format the file, you will notice that `dataFormats` is inside `camelContext` and after `route`. The XSD dictates that `dataFormats` has to come before `route`. Just move it.

Comment: @Sotirios Thanks.  I tried what you suggested and it worked.  I also updated the XML above to help others in the future.