# How do I convert the map returned to Camel into JSON?

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson, apache-camel

This seems like such a simple thing to do, yet I can't seem to find it in the Camel documentation.

Related to my last question i.e., [Get BeanCreationException when try to add Jackson Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306106/get-beancreationexception-when-try-to-add-jackson-library) I now have my code putting the JMS logging response messages into JSON format.

Here's what I currently get when I run my code:

```
23118 [hello.world.request.timer] INFO  hello.world.request  - Exchange[Id:e93861e4-    a5be-4d63-b658-5939f414e595, ExchangePattern:InOnly, Properties:    {CamelToEndpoint=log://hello.world.request?showAll=true, CamelTimerFiredTime=Fri Oct 11     12:03:20 EDT 2013, CamelTimerPeriod=10000, CamelTimerName=hello.world.request.timer},     Headers:{firedTime=Fri Oct 11 12:03:20 EDT 2013}, BodyType:null, Body:null, Out: null]

Returning Map
key= fruit1DataType, value= String
key= fruit1, value= apple
key= fruit1Calories, value= 95
key= fruit1ColorDataType, value= String
key= fruit1CaloriesDataType, value= int
key= fruit1Color, value= red
23122 [hello.world.request.timer] INFO  hello.world.response  - Exchange[Id:e93861e4-    a5be-4d63-b658-5939f414e595, ExchangePattern:InOnly, Properties:    {CamelToEndpoint=log://hello.world.response?showAll=true, CamelTimerFiredTime=Fri Oct 11     12:03:20 EDT 2013, CamelTimerPeriod=10000, CamelTimerName=hello.world.request.timer},     Headers:{firedTime=Fri Oct 11 12:03:20 EDT 2013}, BodyType:byte[], Body:    {"fruit1DataType":"String","fruit1":"apple","fruit1Calories":"95","fruit1ColorDataType":"St    ring","fruit1CaloriesDataType":"int","fruit1Color":"red"}, Out: null]
```

Ideally I'd just like to have Camel convert the contents of the map returned to JSON and print it to the console like this:

```
{"fruit1DataType":"String","fruit1":"apple","fruit1Calories":"95","fruit1ColorDataType":"String","fruit1CaloriesDataType":"int","fruit1Color":"red"}, Out: null]
```

How do I modify my applicationContext.xml to have Camel do this?

Here's my current applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="sample" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <camel:camelContext id="HelloWorldContext">

        <!-- Add Jackson library to render Java Map into JSON -->
        <camel:dataFormats>
          <camel:json id="jack" library="Jackson"/>
        </camel:dataFormats>

        <camel:route>
            <!-- sends a request to the hello world JMS queue every 10 seconds -->
            <camel:from
                uri="timer://hello.world.request.timer?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000" />
            <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.request?level=INFO?showAll=true" />
            <camel:bean ref="helloWorld" />

            <!-- now print out the map in JSON format -->
            <camel:marshal ref ="jack"/>
            <camel:to uri="log:hello.world.response?level=INFO?showAll=true" />
        </camel:route>

    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="transacted" value="false" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost" />
        <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
        <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="prefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
        <property name="queuePrefetch" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="1" />
        <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
        <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="2000" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Camel JSON [endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) in your route to serialize your `Map` to JSON. The link also shows how you can choose which serializer (Jackson is the best choice in my opinion) to use in your endpoint.

Something like this (not exact)

```
<camelContext>
        <dataFormats>
            <json id="serializer" library="Jackson"/>
        </dataFormats>
        <route>
            <from uri="servlet:///test-camel"/>
            <to uri="bean:someSpringBean"/>
            <to uri="bean:anotherSpringBean"/>
            <marshal ref="serializer"/>
        </route>            
</camelContext>
```

Note that the `json` element also takes an attribute called `unmarshalTypeName` for the type to serialize from/deserialize to. However, this defaults to `Map` as described in the link mentioned above. Since you have a `Map`, you don't need to specify.

Comment: I assume you are referencing this example:  <route>
     <from uri="direct:back"/>
     <unmarshal ref="jack"/>
     <to uri="mock:reverse"/>
 </route>  I have tried playing with this, but haven't gotten it to work.  Guess I don't understand the syntax yet.  Could you give me an example related to my applicationContext.xml?

Comment: I found this Camel FAQ page: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html  The section under "Using Spring XML" would be most related to what I want, but how do I use that to serialize my Map to JSON?

Comment: Vidya, could you provide me a simple example of a Camel JSON endpoint?

Comment: Added a snippet that you will need to tweak but hopefully gives the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in an easy way:

```
<route>
    <from id="from1" uri="anyway" />
    <marshal id="_marshal1">
        <json library="Jackson"/>
    </marshal>
    <log id="_log1" message="${body}"/>
    <to id="_to1" uri="mock:foo"/>
</route>
```

And import the dependency in .pom

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```